# Can I limit the size of NFS delayed writes?

Tags: linux, nfs

If mounted with the `async` option, the NFS client in the Linux kernel only rarely flushes writes.

When writing large files over a slow network link, this usually results in all the writes completing in a very short time, much faster than what the network link should allow. At some point (memory pressure, actual flush, or `close()`), the kernel tries to write all its backlog at once, which locks the system call for an indefinite amount of time, sometimes minutes!

Is there a way I can tune the maximum amount of pending data?

Comment: What are your `vm.dirty_ratio` and `vm.dirty_background_ratio` settings on the client?

Comment: Resp. 20 and 10. I haven't touched those settings, but don't they affect all mount points?

Comment: Not sure... 't was just something I had memorized but never used.